# Check object within array for specific string

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to check to see if any of the Objects in my array has the string of "Race Results" within  the **embeds** array. But I am unsure on how to do this.

```
    setup = async () => {
 
      let getListOfMessages = await api.getMessages('1234')

      await timeout(3000)
      
      let result = getListOfMessages.map(({ embeds }) => embeds)
    
    console.log(result)
}
setup())
```

How can I check to see if "**embeds**" has this string within my array of objects? As you can see there are more than 45 objects and I need to check to see if this string exists in order to proceed to the other objective.

Comment: Check values in all properties of those objects or a specific one?

Comment: I need to check all objects for this text. If any of them has this text. It should proceed as TRUE therefore move to the next objective. @charlietfl

Comment: Ok but each object also has multiple properties which is what I am asking

Comment: It needs to check "embed" for this text. See screenshot with arrows.

Comment: Ok and in the image it is contained in first object's `title`. What about in `fields` or `footer`? Just like I  was asking...property specific or any property?

Comment: The embed array will always include just 1. I just need to check to see if the array within embed has this text.

Comment: The array contains an object. That object has multiple properties and nested objects also

Comment: Also not clear what objective is regarding just checking for the string

Comment: Thanks. @aplet123 answer is close to what i need to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use `.some` a lot:

```js
const result = getListOfMessages.some(
    message => message.embeds.some(embed => embed.title === "Race Results")
)
```

This will be a boolean denoting if there is at least one match.

If you want a list of all matches instead of knowing if a match exists, replace the outermost `some` with a `filter`:

```js
const result = getListOfMessages.filter(
    message => message.embeds.some(embed => embed.title === "Race Results")
)
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate more on the Some method. The question does specifically state that they want to check if any of the objects have the string but your code sample indicates that .Some works like Array.filter at first glance and could be confusing to some developers.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am going to try this approach first before I mark it as the answer. @aplet123

Comment: @aplet123, this helped me a lot! Now I am running into an issue where the "getListMessages" is not updating dynamically. I am getting the messages but the messages are not updating within my `runEveryThirty` function. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/BryanBarrera/pen/ae8481b4d75092b8e91da454c6a26156?editors=1010

Comment: @breezy You don't update any of the variables. You should run the whole function every 30 seconds to regenerate `getListOfMessages` and `result`.

Comment: I tried that but when I put everything inside of the `runEveryThirty` function. I get an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @breezy Then make it an `async function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = getListOfMessages.filter(embeds => embeds.title === "Race Results")
```

I believe that will do the trick.

[Simplify your JavaScript – Use .map(), .reduce(), and .filter() - Article on medium.com](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d)